# Firebase + Swift: removeAllObservers not working?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 references (to the same path), one that listens for pending orders and another that listens for completed orders. All for a specific location, which a user can change.

The mechanism I'm using now is this:

1. Create an array that will store Firebase references
2. Before I `observe` the event for pending orders, push that Firebase reference into my array
3. Before I `observe` the event for completed orders, push that Firebase reference into my array
4. When the user switches their location, remove all observers for all references in my array. Empty the array and start listening for pending / completed orders in the new location (steps 2 and 3)

My code looks like this:

```
struct Firebase {

  private let ORDERS_PATH = "locations-orders"

  private static var references = [FIRDatabaseReference]()

  static func observePendingOrders(lId: String, f: @escaping (AppState.Order) -> () ) {
    print("observing orders for \(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")

    let pendingOrdersReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "\(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
    self.references.append(pendingOrdersReference)

    pendingOrdersReference
      .child(dateKeyToday())
      .queryOrdered(byChild: "created_at")
      .observe(.childAdded, with: { firebaseSnapshot in
        ...

        print("order received for \(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
      }
    )
  }

  static func fetchCompletedOrders(lId: String, f: @escaping ([AppState.Order]) -> () ) {
    print("observing completed orders for \(lId)")

    let completedOrdersReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "\(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
    self.references.append(completedOrdersReference)

    completedOrdersReference
      .child(dateKeyToday())
      .queryOrdered(byChild: "status_updated_at")
      .observe(.value, with: { firebaseSnapshot in
        ...
      }
    )
  }

  static func removeAllOrderObservers() {
    for reference in references {
      print("removing reference \(reference)")
      reference.removeAllObservers()
    }
    self.references = []
  }

}
```

However, when I log the location of the orders that I'm watching for, it looks like even after I switch locations the old observers are still listening for orders. Here's my log:

```
observing orders for locations-orders/9RC4H9ZAE457E // first location
observing completed orders for 9RC4H9ZAE457E
removing reference https://mydb-123.firebaseio.com/locations-orders/9RC4H9ZAE457E // switch locations, remove all existing observers for location 9RC4H9ZAE457E
removing reference https://mydb-123.firebaseio.com/locations-orders/9RC4H9ZAE457E
observing orders for locations-orders/1JS53G0TT5ZQD // start listening for orders in new location. notice the new id: 1JS53G0TT5ZQD
observing completed orders for 1JS53G0TT5ZQD
order received for locations-orders/9RC4H9ZAE457E // <-- why is this still showing up?
order received for locations-orders/1JS53G0TT5ZQD
order received for locations-orders/1JS53G0TT5ZQD
order received for locations-orders/9RC4H9ZAE457E // <-- and this one too??
order received for locations-orders/1JS53G0TT5ZQD
order received for locations-orders/1JS53G0TT5ZQD
```

=== UPDATE ===
I even tried handles and it didn't work:

```
struct Firebase {

  private static var handles = [UInt]()
  private static var references = [FIRDatabaseReference]()

  static func observePendingOrders(lId: String, f: @escaping (AppState.Order) -> () ) {
    print("observing orders for \(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")

    let pendingOrdersReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "\(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
    self.references.append(pendingOrdersReference)

    let handle = pendingOrdersReference
      .child(dateKeyToday())
      .queryOrdered(byChild: "created_at")
      .observe(.childAdded, with: { firebaseSnapshot in
        ...
      }
    )

    handles.append(handle)
  }

  static func fetchCompletedOrders(lId: String, f: @escaping ([AppState.Order]) -> () ) {
    print("observing completed orders for \(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")

    let completedOrdersReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "\(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
    self.references.append(completedOrdersReference)

    let handle = completedOrdersReference
      .child(dateKeyToday())
      .queryOrdered(byChild: "status_updated_at")
      .observe(.value, with: { firebaseSnapshot in
        ...
      }
    )
    handles.append(handle)
  }

  static func removeAllOrderObservers() {
//    for reference in references {
//      print("removing reference \(reference)")
//      reference.removeAllObservers()
//    }
//    
    if !references.isEmpty {
      let ref = references[0]
      for handle in handles {
        print("removing handle \(handle)")
        ref.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
      }
      self.references = []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My first question is; why are you doing this? Once you add an observer it keeps observing and will call the closure upon an associated event. Keeping a reference to it in an array isn't needed. In this case, any event that occurs in the Orders node is going to notify your app.

Comment: Hey Jay. The app is used like this: the user selects a location and sees all orders for that location. When the order switches the location, it should now only show the orders for the new location, not the old one

Comment: It also looks like you are observing .childAdded and .value for the same location?

Comment: yeh there are two tables on the screen: one for new orders (child added) and the other for completed orders (existing orders that have status == "completed", which is done by swiping on the new orders table)

Comment: Oh - and you may want to use the firebase handle instead of the reference and then use removeObserverWithHandle to remove the observer.

Comment: @Jay I tried it and it didn't work (updated the question)

Answer (score 1):

I think I might've fixed it? So it was because I'm actually observing on a child node of that reference so removing all observers for the parent node does not do anything because you have to remove it at the specific node you're observing.

```
let pendingOrdersReference = FIRDatabase
  .database()
  .reference(withPath: "\(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
  .child(dateKeyToday()) // <---- added this thing
```

This is my final solution, which seems to be working:

```
struct Firebase {
  private static var references = [FIRDatabaseReference]()

  static func observePendingOrders(lId: String, f: @escaping (AppState.Order) -> () ) {
    print("observing orders for \(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")

    let pendingOrdersReference = FIRDatabase
      .database()
      .reference(withPath: "\(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
      .child(dateKeyToday())
    self.references.append(pendingOrdersReference)

    ...
  }

  static func fetchCompletedOrders(lId: String, f: @escaping ([AppState.Order]) -> () ) {
    print("observing completed orders for \(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")

    let completedOrdersReference = FIRDatabase
      .database()
      .reference(withPath: "\(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
      .child(dateKeyToday())
    self.references.append(completedOrdersReference)

    ...

  }

  static func removeAllOrderObservers() {
    for reference in references {
      print("removing reference \(reference)")

      reference.removeAllObservers()
    }
    self.references = []
  }

}
```